# Thread in C++11 VC++2010

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, visual-c++-2010

I need to use threads with Visual Studio 2010, but that doesn't support C++ thread library (I can't use just library). Does anybody know another way?

Comment: [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/thread.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I have always preferred to use the beginthreadex functions on windows.  Docs are [msdn beginthreadex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

It is supported across all versions on windows and its compilers

Answer (score 3):

There are many different threading libraries that you can use in Windows.

If you want to use support from library, you can use [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread.html), [Poco::Thread](http://pocoproject.org/slides/130-Threads.pdf) threading support from [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/) or even [Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qthread.html). However, you can still use Win32 support for threading in form of [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and its variants.